# Is a "factory" method the right pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

So I'm working to improve an existing implementation. I have a number of polymorphic classes that are all composed into a higher level container class. The problem I'm dealing with at the moment is that the higher level container class, well, sucks. It looks something like this, which I really don't have a problem with (as the polymorphic classes in the container should be public). My real issue is the constructor...

```
/*
 * class1 and class 2 derive from the same superclass
 */
class Container 
{
  public: 
   boost::shared_ptr<ComposedClass1> class1;  
   boost::shared_ptr<ComposedClass2> class2;
  private:
   ...
}

/*
 * Constructor - builds the objects that we need in this container. 
 */ 
Container::Container(some params)
{
  class1.reset(new ComposedClass1(...));
  class2.reset(new ComposedClass2(...));
}
```

What I really need is to make this container class more re-usable. By hard-coding up the member objects and instantiating them, it basically isn't and can only be used once. A factory is one way to build what I need (potentially by supplying a list of objects and their specific types to be created?) Other ways to get around this problem? Seems like someone should have solved it before... Thanks!

Comment: Any details about what the container is supposed to do? Is it trying to reimplement polymorphism? Will the pointers be reset to some other objects later?

Comment: no, not reimplementing polymorphism. It's just a container for a number of "components". In general, a set of components do something interesting. You can form a different container with a different set of components and do something else interesting.  There would be no reason to reset the pointers AFAIK.

Comment: Way too abstract to give a useful answer except by chance. Are you to trying to re-use the same container instance with different class1 and class2s or are you trying to re-use a different instance of the container? Probably DI (William Billingsley's response) will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that Tom. In re-reading it, I agree. 

You would be using different instances of the container. So you would have 

Container container1;
Container container2;

and each would have different composed classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) springs to mind.

Comment: thanks for the link. in reading the link, I'm pretty sure this is what i'm looking for, hence you win! :-) thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You use a factory method if you change the created type in derived classes, i.e. if descendants of Container use different descendants of class1 and class2.

```
class1* Container::GetClass1; virtual;
{
  return new ComposedClass1;
}

class1* SpecialContainer::GetClass1;
{
  return new SpecialComposedClass1;
}

Container::Container(some params)
{
  class1.reset(GetClass1);
  class2.reset(GetClass2);
}
```

A different approach is decoupling creation of Container's dependencies from Container.
For starters, you can change the constructor to dependency-inject class1 and class2.

```
Container::Container(aclass1, aclass2)
{
  class1.reset(aclass1);
  class2.reset(aclass2);
}
```

Comment: This approach is normally fine, but you should not use factory methods in a constructor (constructors should not call virtual methods, as they are executing on a class before has finished constructing).  I would recommend an abstract factory instead with dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You do know you can just have a second constructor that doesn't do that right?

```
Container::Container(some params)
{
    // any other initialization you need to do
}
```

You can then set class1 and class2 as you please as they're public.

Of course they shouldn't be but given this code that's what you could do.

As far as I can see from what you've described the factory pattern wouldn't be that helpful.

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but the problem is that a different instance of the container may not even need Class1 and Class2 composed into it. It may have Class3, 4, and 5 as objects composed into it. Trying to find a general way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class factory
{
    public static Class1 Create()
      {
            return new Class1();
      }
}

class Class1
{}
main()
{
   Classs1 c=factory.Create();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I would recommend an Abstract Factory passed into the constructor.

```
class ClassFactory {
public:
   virtual ~ClassFactory
   virtual Class1 * createClass1(...) = 0;  // obviously these are real params not varargs
   virtual Class2 * createClass2(...) = 0;
};

class DefaultClassFactory : public ClassFactory {
    //  ....
};


Container::Container(
    some params, 
    boost::smart_ptr<ClassFactory> factory = boost::smart_ptr<ClassFactory>(new DefaultClassFactory))
{
  class1.reset(factory->createClass1(...));
  class2.reset(factory->createClass1(...));
}
```

This is a form of dependency injection without the framework.  Normal clients can use the `DefaultClassFactory` transparently as before.  Other clients for example unit tests can inject their own `ClassFactory` implementation.

Depending on how you want to control ownership of the `factory` parameter this could be a smart_ptr, scoped_ptr or a reference.  The reference can lead to slightly cleaner syntax.

```
Container::Container(
    some params, 
    ClassFactory & factory = DefaultClassFactory())
{
    class1.reset(factory.createClass1(...));
    class2.reset(factory.createClass1(...));
}

void SomeClient()
{
    Container c(some params, SpecialClassFactory());
    // do special stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I agree with Toms comment: not enough info.

Based on your clarification:

> *It's just a container for a number of "components"*

If the list of components varies, provide Add/Enumerate/Remove methods on the container.

If the list of components should be fixed for each instance of the container, provide a builder object with the methods

```
Builder.AddComponent
Builder.CreateContainer
```

The first would allow to reuse the container, but often ends up more complex in my experience. The second one often requires a way to swap / replace containers but ends up easier to implement.

Dependency Injection libraries can help you configure the actual types outside of the aplication (though I still need to see why this is such a great leap forward).